# Display an uneditable event in Primefaces schedule

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, schedule

I'm new to Java and newer to Primefaces. I have a problem trying to display an all day event on the Primefaces schedule. I have the schedule set to only show from 8.30 to 17.30. Is there an restriction I have to make in the schedule bean to make it less than an all day event? What do I need to add/takeaway from my java code to create an event? Here is the Java code:

```
package com.ait.project;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import org.primefaces.model.DefaultScheduleEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultScheduleModel;
import org.primefaces.model.ScheduleModel;




@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ScheduleBean {
    private ScheduleModel model;
    private ScheduleModel eventModel;
    private boolean allDaySlot;
    
    
    public ScheduleBean() {
        
        eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();

        DefaultScheduleEvent event1 = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
        event1.setTitle("Example Event");
        event1.setAllDay(allDaySlot);
    }


    public ScheduleModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }


    public void setModel(ScheduleModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }


    public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
        return eventModel;
    }


    public void setEventModel(ScheduleModel eventModel) {
        this.eventModel = eventModel;
    }


    public boolean isAllDaySlot() {
        return allDaySlot;
    }


    public void setAllDaySlot(boolean allDaySlot) {
        this.allDaySlot = allDaySlot;
    }
    
}
```

and the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 

<h:head></h:head> 
<body> 
<div class="schedule">
    <h:form>
        <div class="text"> Our Availability</div>
        <h:panelGrid columnClasses="value">
        <p:schedule value="#{scheduleBean.eventModel}" editable="false" widgetVar="myschedule" view="listDay" timeFormat="HH:mm" axisFormat="H:mm" minTime="8:30" maxTime="17:30">
            
        </p:schedule>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: First problem i see if that you are not adding the Event to your model with `eventModel.addEvent(event);`

Comment: Maybe take a look at the scheduler Primefaces [documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/schedule)